# Provide translation token from nested keys in json format file Angular i18n

Tags: angular, internationalization

I am new to angular localize support.
As translations now can be extracted to json format also , I have seen it does not support translation token as nested keys from json format file.

for example if below is the markup

`<span i18n="@@parent.child>`
`Test translation`
`</span>`

and extracting it using json format like below generates messages.json file like bellow

ng extract-i18n --format=json --output-path src/locale

`{`
`"parnet.child":"Test translation"`
`}`

But, to group translation in logical manner shouldn't be like
`{`
`"parent":{`
`"child": "Test translation "`
`}`
`}`

Is there anything already present in framework to make it like above or not supported at all ?